# Mark as deprecated third party class

Tags: java, refactoring, deprecated

I have some third party library *Foo* with class *FooBar*. I think that class *FooBar* is badly designed. I want to write my own *MyBar* as adapter pattern. Can I mark the original *FooBar* as `@Deprecated` without modifying its code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`@deprecated`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html) should be added to the source to flag the class/method as deprecated. So you cannot deprecate someone else's code.

However if you have a better alternative that you prefer to use in your project as a *standard*, then you can impose this standard in other ways, as a rule in [checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) for instance.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot mark it as deprecated without compiling so will need the source

Comment: You probably *could* do some bytecode-manipulation to add the [deprecation attribute](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#78232). But I don't think it's worth it.

Comment: Thanks, actually I have the source. But I do not wont do any modifications in it. First of all, other team members can easily forget about using modified lib. Secondly, it will make new issue in build and distributive process and I'm not sure can I do code modification by license.

Comment: @Stas - the deprecation flag is in the compiled classes.  1)  If you can't ensure that your team members are going to use the right version of the compiled class, you are basically screwed.  2)  If you have source code but are not allowed to recompile it ... or tweak the binaries ... you have a seriously weird license!!

Comment: @Stephen, 1) It's embarrassing( 2) Very likely I can do such modification. But I really don't know. Probably I should consult with lawyer about.

Comment: @Stas - I wouldn't don't worry with the lawyers unless the legalese is unintelligible ... or unless you can see a way that what you are doing might *possibly* be harmful to the interests of the s/w vendor; i.e. that they might care.  (But hey, IANAL :-)

Comment: @Stephen Thanks for advise :) Actually, I should think more about redistribute modified lib)

Comment: @Stas - you don't need to redistribute the modified lib.  Just use it for building.  In fact, you only need to use it for test builds.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, use your IDE's "find references" function to find all places where your code uses the offending class.  Or use "grep".

Comment: Yeah, thanks. But the real task prevent `FooBar` usages in _future_.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, one could change the class file adding the deprecated annotation to the class. (But I'm not proficient with the tools needed to do this.)

Comment: Yeah. I can. But there can be new member in project how can decided to use original library. Probably, some checkstyle util will be best solution.